# A popup like thing appears while executing my selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get a "popup" like them which asks for some user credentials(which i have) randomly when i run my script. I say "popup like" as its not a popup, frame.

How to overcome this?
Any help?

Thanks,
S. K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is NOT complete. If it's an Authentication pop-up, we can provide credential in the URL itself like the following
`http://username:password@Website_URL` e.g. `http://username:password@www.xyz.com`

So, instead of writing

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://Website_URL");
```

Write the following piece of code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://username:password@Website_URL");
```

See if this works!

Comment: Hello mfsi_sitamj, I really appreciate your answer. Yes it is an Authentication pop-up. Now it comes again and again 'randomly'. so this 'driver.get' will help only the first time...what to do if it comes again.  Thanks S.K

Comment: Use Robot utility in Java. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html